# Nodemon + Express 4.13.4

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am losing my mind trying to get Nodemon running correctly with Express 4 ;) I have installed the npm and changed my package.json to

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
```

I launch the server using...

```
npm start
```

If I then make any edits to a routes.js file no changes take. Even when I refresh the browser. After running ps aux | grep node I get the following..

[image]

It seems that BOTH the Nodemon AND node server are running. Has anyone else seen this and understand why? or how to fix it?

Thanks.

*UPDATE This is my console output while the server is running.

[image]

Comment: The `node /usr/local/bin/nodemon ./bin/www` is nodemon watching your app for changes. The `node ./bin/www` process is your app proper (which will have been forked by nodemon). I've no idea why changing your files isn't causing nodemon to restart the app though.

Comment: Hmmm ok. It seems to work fine for jade files. Its only for route files that it seems to not be working. Thank you @TomJardine-McNamara I updated with an image of my servers console. Not sure if that helps....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodemon [only watches the files in the current working directory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories) (in your case `./bin` because you're running `./bin/www`). Your app files aren't in that directory, so nodemon isn't watching them.

You can, however, tell nodemon to instead watch one or more other directories. In your case you just need to tell it to watch the project root, i.e. `nodemon ./bin/www --watch .`.

Your jade files are loaded anew on every request by express's view engine, which is why you were seeing changes made in them without you or nodemon restarting the app.

I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/barrylachapelle/temprepo/pull/1) on your repo which makes `npm start` use nodemon in this fashion.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Jardine-McNamara it still doesn't seem to work. I pushed my app to github. If you have two seconds you'd really be helping me out ;)  

https://github.com/barrylachapelle/temprepo

Comment: When I'm back home today I'll take a look :)

Comment: Although a quick glance at your code shows you don't have an `app/` folder. You could tell nodemon to watch the project root (`nodemon -w . bin/www`), or move your app code into an `app` folder and use `nodemon -w app bin/www` (I usually do this because I end up with multiple folders e.g. `lib`, `config` and to keep non-app files (any tooling, etc) separate)

Comment: Thank you! Tom! So much appreciated.